# Reset Multipart/Form-Data Object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, file-upload, multipartform-data

Assume a user has uploaded a few pictures into the 'input' tag.  How do you empty (aka reset) the 'input' tag below with jQuery?

```
<form id="ImgForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="pictures[]" type="file" multiple />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#ImgForm input[type="file"]').val('');
```

**OR**

```
$('#ImgForm').reset(); // will reset form.
```

**OR**

```
// trigger reset button click event manually
$('#ImgForm input[type="reset"]).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reset your form using `reset`

```
$('#ImgForm').each(function(){
   this.reset();
});
```

If you want to make remove/empty its value

```
$('#ImgForm input[type="file"]').val('');
```